# Understanding qsort() function

Tags: c, qsort

```
int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
  return ( (int) (*(float*)a - *(float*)b) );
}
```

When I want to use `qsort` function, I should write a compare function in this form as I understood. So, why we are using void before the parameters of compare function?

And, is this compare function standard with its parameters and code in curly braces or can we simply change the code and even parameters through our wishes?

Comment: Because a `void` pointer is kind of "generic" pointer that can be casted to and from any other pointer types. The only "standard" here is the function signature (I.e. the parameters and return types)

Comment: Because `qsort` want's function pointer to an `int foo(const void *a, const void *b)` function.

Comment: Aside: the difference between `float`s might not be in the range of `int`. Make the comparisons, and return 1, -1 or 0. In the last case, you don't need to check for equality since you already checked greater or less.

Comment: On a completely different topic than the `void*` arguments...Is it possible that for some values of `float`, `f1` and `f2`, that rounding might cause `f1 - f2` to round to 0 but `f2- f1` to round to a non-zero value?  I'm not an expert in floating point numeric analysis (so I don't know if I'm asking about nonsense), but that seems like the kind of trap that floating point arithmetic might have.

Comment: Even when the values compared are `int` you should not return their difference as the function value, since that can overflow. Make the comparisons, and return 1, -1 or 0.

Comment: As @MichaelBurr says, `0.2 - 0.1` returned as `int` will return `0`, when the first is obviously greater.

Comment: Rather than `return ( (int) (*(float*)a - *(float*)b) );`, recommend `return (*(float*)a > *(float*)b) - (*(float*)a < *(float*)b);`.  If concerned about NaNs, then another form should be used.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can not change the parameters or the return type.
But of course you can change the 'code' of the function. You can compare whatever you want. The only important thing is the return value:

[taken from here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/qsort.3.html):

The return value should be `<0` if the first passed parameter is 'lower' than the second, `== 0` if both are identic or `>0` if the first one is 'greater'.

For example you could use a qsort function with strings like this:

```
int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
    return strcmp((char *) a, (char *) b);
}
```

Comment: So, Can't i change the parameter type as  char instead of void ? Here, it's obvious with the codes in curly brackets, we are going to use this function for char type datas.

Comment: No you cannot, as qsort has a specific type for it's 4th argument: `int (*compar)(const void *, const void *)` which requires the both parameters to be `const void *`

Answer (score 1):

In C `void *` means that you can store a pointer of any type in it. Imagine that you wanted to sort a list of strings(char *), what would you do? Write one implementation of `qsort` for `int` data type and one for `char *`? Here, `qsort` is written using `void *` to allow you to compare different stuff with different types.

Yes, the parameter type is standard. See the definition of it in `stdlib.h`.

```
void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
       int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

Comment: A `void *` more means that it can store the *pointer* to any type in it. A `void *` is always the same type, with `sizeof(void *) == sizeof(intptr_t)`.

Comment: @Kupiakos: To be accurate the constrain is: `sizeof(void *) <= sizeof(intptr_t)`

Answer (score 0):

The reason why void pointers are used is because they can be cast into other pointer types and then back into void pointers without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

`qsort` is using a `callback` that allows you to use arbitrary datatypes and then inside the comparator you can sort them any way you please. You just need to adhere to the API.

This provides a lot of flexibility. The code below is a simplified example but it could have been extended to sort arbitrary data structures easily. In all cases the same `qsort` function is used ie the very same function at the same address is called.

The following contrived example might help to understand why it's flexible. Note, instead of `int` the comparator `func_table` could be extended to be a table of structures where each one has a comparator type. To reiterate, the same qsort function is called in each case, its the callback functions address that changes to the correct function required to sort the data at runtime.

The following program sorts an array in a random direction where the sort function is chosen from a table.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define ARRAY_SIZE(arr) (sizeof(arr) / sizeof((arr)[0]))

int  values[] = {  3 , 88 , 52 , 285, 63 , 288 , 576 , 10, 21 , 5,343 , 38 , 55 , 100, 552 , 85 };

typedef int (*comparator)(const void * a, const void * b);

int cmp_reverse(const void * a, const void * b) {
  return ( *(int*)b - *(int*)a );
}

int cmp_int(const void * a, const void * b) {
  return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}

static comparator func_table[2];

int main(void) {
  srand(time(NULL));
  size_t int_arr_size = ARRAY_SIZE(values);
  int n = 0;
  int i = 0;
  func_table[0] = cmp_int;
  func_table[1] = cmp_reverse;
  while(i++ < 10) {
    int order = rand() % 2 == 0;
    printf("order: %d %s ", order, order == 0 ? ">" : "<");
    qsort(values, int_arr_size, sizeof(int), func_table[order]);
    for( n = 0 ; n < int_arr_size; n++ ) {   
      printf("%d ", values[n]);
    }
    printf("<\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```